# Ace editor in SVG Foreign Object

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, ace-editor

How would one add an [Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) to a [D3 SVG](http://d3js.org/)? Is this possible? What is the best way to go about doing so?

Below is my attempt to to create a foreignObject element and add the editor to it, to no avail:

```js
    var w = window.innerWidth,
      h = window.innerHeight;

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', w)
      .attr('height', h);

    var group = svg.append("g");

    var radius = w / 4;

    var circle = group.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", w / 2)
      .attr("cy", h / 2)
      .attr("r", radius)
      .attr("fill", "black");

    group.append('foreignObject')
      .attr("x", w / 2 - radius / 2)
      .attr("y", h / 2 - radius / 2)
      .attr("width", radius)
      .attr("height", radius)
      .style("background-color", "red")
      .append("xhtml:div")
      .attr("id", "editor")
      .attr('width', '50')
      .attr('height', '50');

    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.9/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In html width and height are CSS styles, not attributes. Once I fixed that and made it big enough to see, the editor seemed to work for me, at least in Firefox which is where I tested it.

```js
    var w = window.innerWidth,
      h = window.innerHeight;

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', w)
      .attr('height', h);

    var group = svg.append("g");

    var radius = w / 4;

    var circle = group.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", w / 2)
      .attr("cy", h / 2)
      .attr("r", radius)
      .attr("fill", "black");

    group.append('foreignObject')
      .attr("x", w / 2 - radius / 2)
      .attr("y", h / 2 - radius / 2)
      .attr("width", radius)
      .attr("height", radius)
      .style("background-color", "red")
      .append("xhtml:div")
      .attr("id", "editor")
      .attr('style', 'width: 350px;height: 50px;');


    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.9/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```